# Complement property for standard normal functions

Tags: calculus, probability

[image]

Why do we need to use integrals to show that $F\left(-x\right)=\:1\:-\:F\left(x\right)$ ? Isn't that obvious for a symmetric normal distribution?

Comment: It may be obvious, but your teacher will give you 0 for that answer...

Comment: Please use Mathjax to write the equations